# Show one Dialog Instance when Hotkey is pressed

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with Qt , im trying to call a QDialog only once when a specific Hotkey is pressed but i keep getting multiple QDialog.
I tried

```
private:
ProductsDlg * pd;
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setCentralWidget(ui->MainTabWidget);
    setFixedHeight(481);
    setFixedWidth(335);

    RegisterHotKey(HWND(winId()) , 0 , NULL , VK_F9);

    //pd = new ProductsDlg(this); // I USED THIS TO TRY if(pd->isVisible()) Down in the Hotkey press Event.
}

bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType , void *message , long *result)
{
    Q_UNUSED(eventType);
    Q_UNUSED(result);

    MSG * msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if(msg->message == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        if(!pd)
        {
            pd = new ProductsDlg(this);
            pd->show();
        }
    }
}
```

I know im doing something wrong because this one crashes after i close the QDialog and i press the Hotkey again.
I've tried if(!pd->isVisible()) on the Hotkey event but didnt really do anything too.
Does the global "dp" get deleted when the QDialog is closed ?
BTW im using setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); on that QDialog if that affects anything.

EDIT : I was thinking about a way to only create the QDialog once and just show it and hide it when the Hotkey is called , but i couldnt see how its done , i still get a crash.

Thanks

Comment: `pd` is keeping a dangling pointer to the old `QDialog` after it has been deleted when closed, `if(!pd)` will be true only for the first time. . .

Comment: You may use `QShortcut` instead of WinAPI.

Comment: @Mike , Yes thats what i thought at first , any solution around it ? i've tried using a variable that sets to FALSE when the QDialog is closed (the Destructor of the QDialog sets it to false when its called) but nothing , and i didnt like that method.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov , but please note that [`RegisterHotKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) Defines a *system-wide* hot key. while [`QShortcut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html) can only provide *application-wide* shortcut key (meaning that one of the application's windows must be active) . So, if an *application-wide* shortcut is sufficient, using `QShortcut` would be far better as it is cross-platform and easier to implement.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov No i really need a system-wide shortcut in my case

Comment: your `nativeEvent` implementation seems to be wrong too, as you should return `false` for events that you don't process, so that it is passed back to Qt, which translates the event into a Qt event and sends it to the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just used the Show / Hide method and it worked for me ... i think my problem was around using one global object and using it multiple times knowing that it will be deleted when the QDialog is closed so as @Mike said !dp only works at the first time.

Since my QDialog is frameless and since its closed by a hotkey too , so ive used hiding instead of closing it.

```
if(!dp->isVisible())
{
    dp->show();
}
else
{
    dp->hide();
}
```

And this is what i needed (Same Hotkey Shows and Hides).

Thanks for all of your answers !